# Noch vs. auch vs. außerdem

Tags: word-choice, word-order

Which one of the following sentences is correct, or are all acceptable?

> Meine Hobbys sind kochen, schwimmen und Fahrrad fahren. Ich lese noch gerne.

Vs.

> Meine Hobbys sind kochen, schwimmen und Fahrrad fahren. Ich lese auch gerne.

Vs.

> Meine Hobbys sind kochen, schwimmen und Fahrrad fahren. Ich lese außerdem gerne / Außerdem lese ich gerne.

I know I can just add "und lesen" to the first sentence and save me the hassle, but I would like to know how to say (I also like reading) as a separate sentence.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about what you're trying to say here in these sentences. It's possible to be grammatically correct but not have the meaning you intended. I'm pretty sure the *noch* version doesn't mean what you think it means, but I can't say for certain since you didn't say what that was.

Comment: @RDBury This is what I want to say: "My hobbies are cooking, swimming and cycling. I also like reading".

Comment: Mind the capitalization of nouns: "Meine Hobbys sind Kochen, Schwimmen und Fahrradfahren."

Answer (score 4):

> Ich lese noch gerne.

This could mean: I still enjoy reading. (But also could imply: you might stop  enjoying it soon?)

> Meine Hobbys sind kochen, schwimmen und Fahrrad fahren. Ich lese auch
> gerne.

This is simple and straight forward. It tells what you like

> Meine Hobbys sind kochen, schwimmen und Fahrrad fahren, außerdem lese ich gerne.

This would be the "prettiest" version. (Your other version is also correct).
Very well put!

Cheers

Comment: I disagree with your analysis of "noch". "Noch" has more than one meaning. https://www.dwds.de/wb/noch#d-1-1-3

Comment: that's true. it has more than one meaning but its not really good style to use it in this context. it could mean any of my options or even something else. But this would depend on the context of the sentences. ( i changed the answer accordingly)

Answer (score 3):

They meaning is the same. But to say "Ich lese noch gerne" gives the reading a bit of a very secondary importance.